# Issue in Rollback (after rolling upgrade) from hadoop 2.7.2 to 2.5.2

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, upgrade, rollback

Did rolling upgrade from hadoop 2.5.2 to hadoop 2.7.2 and **did not finalize** the upgrade. Now I wished to rollback to 2.5.2 version based on [reference](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsRollingUpgrade.html#Rollback).

Starting Name node 1 as active with **-rollingUpgrade rollback**, it gets shuts down with the following exception,

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.IncorrectVersionException: Unexpected version of storage directory ..\Metadata\data\dfs\namenode. Reported: -63. Expecting = -57.
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.StorageInfo.setLayoutVersion(StorageInfo.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.StorageInfo.setFieldsFromProperties(StorageInfo.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.setFieldsFromProperties(NNStorage.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.StorageInfo.readProperties(StorageInfo.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:955)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1473)
16/10/13 12:45:13 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
16/10/13 12:45:13 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at myserver25/192.1.100.26
************************************************************/
```

There is already a task regarding this but the status is Open.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-9096

Please let me know are there any **work around** to rollback HDFS from rolling upgrade without any issues.

Similar query already posted with different hadoop version:
[Issue in Rollback (after rolling upgrade) from hadoop 2.7.1 to 2.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493851/issue-in-rollback-after-rolling-upgrade-from-hadoop-2-7-1-to-2-4-0)

Thanks,

Dinesh Kumar P